# PrestaShop migrate clients info to OpenCart

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to move the clients database from PrestaShop to OpenCart. In this endeavor I found that there are some sites which can automate this process but at a fairly high price for what I need.

I just have 200 or so clients and if I can't find a way of exporting their login details to OpenCart I will do them manually but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, so is there a free or cheap way which would allow me to transfer the clients details to the new platform?

The trouble I'm having is getting the password of my customers, if I could get that then I could manually transfer them to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the passwords of your clients directly, because they are encrypted. What you can do is to import them as they are and change the way OpenCart decrypts them. 
PrestaShop is using the following encryption:

md5(concat(_COOKIE_KEY_, 'CUSTOMER_PASSWORD'))
i.e. concatenated "key" and "password"
where _COOKIE_KEY_ is a constant from /config/settings.php

In OpenCart the change must be done in the following file:

\admin\model\user\user.php

The other ways is just to let it as it is and your customers will reset their passwords via the "Forgot Password" functionality. You can also send them emails, informing them about that switch of the software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

In the end I've decided to export the clients details (from PhpMyAdmin) to a CSV file wich I later sorted out.


Then by hand I've transfered all the clients details ... except their passwords wich was solved by a password reset notification email.

Not the greatest way to go about it but on a low budget you do what you can.

The thing was that I didn't even had the time to look into how would I go about changing OpenCart's decription system wich would have been great.